# If I bought two of the same game but didn't give me an extra copy, can I refund one?

Tags: steam, payday-2

So recently I just bought Payday 2. One day after I bought Payday 2 GOTY edition because I wanted the DLC. It told me in my purchase that I wouldn't receive an extra copy of Payday 2. But I would still be buying Payday 2. So I said ok and didn't remove Payday 2 from my cart. So now I have two copies but can't gift either. So I refunded the first (Non-GOTY) edition. The refund hasn't gone through yet but will I still have the GOTY of Payday I purchased? Or will I have to purchase Payday 2 again even though technically I own two copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You'll keep your Payday 2.

The way steam works is a bit complicated. You don't buy *games*, you buy subs. You refunded the [sub with only Payday 2 in it](https://steamdb.info/sub/30182/apps/), but you still have the [GOTY sub](https://steamdb.info/sub/54408/apps/), and that has the base game in it too, so you should be ok.